# How to implement user specific dashboards in Microsoft PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We have a multi tenant webapp which is used by around 300/400 users and growing. We want to use PowerBI to visualize the data and embed it inside our web app. Our ultimate goal is that each user can have their own dashboard based on their role and if PowerBI allows we also want users to edit dashboards from within the Web App. Is it possible? What should be the best practice to implement it and what type of Power BI license would it require?

App: MVC 5 Azure Web App
Database: Azure SQL database with Row Level Security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to edit dashboards in Power BI Embedded, only [reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-interact-with-a-report-in-editing-view). So lets assume each user will have his own report. When a new user is registered, you can use [Clone Report In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/clonereportingroup) API to provide a standard template report to start with.

When embedding, there are two models - user owns data and app owns data. In the first mode each user needs Power BI Pro license, while in the second you need a single "master" account with Pro license. It is highly recommended to buy a dedicated capacity by purchasing [Power BI Premium](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/calculator/) or [Power BI Embedded](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/power-bi-embedded/).

For best practices and details about the implementation, you can read [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content into an application for your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-your-organization) article.

Comment: Apart from the answer, here are some more links that I've found very useful:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-multi-tenancy
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded-faq

I've also learnt that "app owns data" model is the way forward.